# Mongo db C# update.SetWrapped method not invoking Custom Bson Serializer

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver

I have implemented a custom Bson Serializer, this Custom BsonSerializer seems to work fine on Save and getting mongo documents. But when trying to do an update it doesn't seem to invoke serializer.

Just FYI,
I've added DecimalSerializer which serializes decimal to an Int32 value and on deserialization it converts back to an Decimal value. So while updating a decimal value it is not invoking any serializer.

Update statement: `Update.SetWrapped("Tiers.$.Price", tier.Price)`, this is getting saved as string type in mongo db.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though certain builds of the Driver do not run the bson serializer on Update

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/e455c963cb385b94fdcd02d1e53b536b47663239/src/MongoDB.Driver/MongoCollection.cs

```
    public virtual WriteConcernResult Update(IMongoQuery query, IMongoUpdate update, MongoUpdateOptions options)
    {
        var updateBuilder = update as UpdateBuilder;
        if (updateBuilder != null)
        {
            if (updateBuilder.Document.ElementCount == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Update called with an empty UpdateBuilder that has no update operations.");
            }
        }

        if (options == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("options");
        }

        var queryDocument = query == null ? new BsonDocument() : query.ToBsonDocument();
        var updateDocument = update.ToBsonDocument();
        var messageEncoderSettings = GetMessageEncoderSettings();
        var isMulti = options.Flags.HasFlag(UpdateFlags.Multi);
        var isUpsert = options.Flags.HasFlag(UpdateFlags.Upsert);
        var writeConcern = options.WriteConcern ?? _settings.WriteConcern ?? WriteConcern.Acknowledged;

        var operation = new UpdateOpcodeOperation(_collectionNamespace, queryDocument, updateDocument, messageEncoderSettings)
        {
            IsMulti = isMulti,
            IsUpsert = isUpsert,
            WriteConcern = writeConcern
        };

        using (var binding = _server.GetWriteBinding())
        {
            return operation.Execute(binding, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
```

But does happen on save

```
    public virtual WriteConcernResult Save(Type nominalType, object document, MongoInsertOptions options)
    {
        if (nominalType == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("nominalType");
        }
        if (document == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("document");
        }

        var serializer = BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(document.GetType());
```

This to me really stems from the fact that the serializer would likely have to have the entire object, and when doing an Update the entire object never comes to the client.  This is likely expected.  Your options:

1. Manually serialize tier.Price before setWrapped
2. Check to see if another version of the driver works (might not be worth it)
3. Bug report to MongoDB Issues (info on Github page)
4. Avoid using the custom serializer for decimal types (BSON natively has double data types)